# In php, how can I sort an array of lines by date when each line contains both a date and some additional text?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my php array content which I want to sort by descending date order. Each line will start with a date. There will be more than one word in each line:

```
$newarray = [
    "8-06-2001 fish",
    "10-09-2020 chips",
    "3-07-2020 peas",
    "9-09-2005 chicken",
    "5-05-1999 veg",
    "20-04-1998 sausage",
    "1-04-1998 haddock",
    "7-04-1998 cod",
    "3-04-1998 curry",
    "7-09-2005 burger",
    "1-09-2005 cheese"
];
```

I tried this function, but it's no good for both text and date:

```
// DATE SORT FUNCTION
$compare_function = function($a,$b) {$a_timestamp = strtotime($a); // convert string date to a int timestamp
$b_timestamp = strtotime($b); 
if ($a_timestamp > $b_timestamp) {return -1;}
elseif ($a_timestamp < $b_timestamp) {return 1;} else {return 0;}};

// USE FUNCTION
usort($newarray, $compare_function)
```

Comment: Given the example data, what order do you expect them to be in after sorting?

Comment: I want the latest date at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `strtotime` will return false if you pass it a non-datetime string. `"8-06-2001 fish"` is not a datetime string, as "fish" isn't a date or a time. As such, your `strtotime` calls are all returning false, and your sort isn't working.

In order to extract the date string from your strings, you'll want to split the strings so you've only got your date string. The character which delimits your date string and the rest (i.e. the character which splits `"8-06-2001"` and `"fish"`) is `" "`.

So, you need to split your string at the `" "`. To do this, use `explode(" ", $string)`, which returns an array. The first element in this array (i.e. `[0]`) is the string before the first `" "`.

Here's the code as it should be:

```php
    // DATE SORT FUNCTION
    $compare_function = function($a,$b) {
        $a_timestamp = strtotime(explode(" ", $a)[0]); // convert string date to a int timestamp
        $b_timestamp = strtotime(explode(" ", $b)[0]);
        if ($a_timestamp > $b_timestamp) {return -1;}
        elseif ($a_timestamp < $b_timestamp) {return 1;} else {return 0;}
    };

    // USE FUNCTION
    usort($newarray, $compare_function)
```

Comment: perfect; thanks very much; this works. I couldnt find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Hopefully my explanation helps you understand it too :)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` is not returning an integer when there's a non-time piece in the string. Try

```
strtotime(current(explode(' ', $a)))
```

instead. This breaks up the string at spaces, takes the first piece, and just does `strtotime` on that.

Comment: thanks but I cant work out how to implement string to time with explode. I've been trying and I will keep trying though and see if i can work it out.